Axial force of cone on two rollers
I have a technical challenge, where I need to properly evaluate the axial force of the cylinder (D) rolling on two rollers (d).
Data of axial force is needed, because I need to properly design the front and back stopper for the pipe. And because of lack of space (too much to explain here) it is necessary to properly evaluate the force so I don't overdimension the stoppers.
The reason that axial force comes into play is that the big cylinder (D) can be a bit conically shaped. Cylinder (D), in my case, is a pipe with a maximum diameter of 4000 mm and a mass of around 10.000 kg.
Can anyone please point me in the proper direction on how to evaluate this, or have any similar problems known that I can build on?


The stoppers need to be able to overcome the dry friction. So calculate the contact force and multiply by the coefficient of friction.

Are the rollers fixed, i.e., will their axis still be parallel even for conical pipe?

I agree with the friction comment. One thing I forgot to mention, is that this conical shape is very small, only from tolerances of production errors. In theory all three axes are parallel, but in real life pipe will travel to one or the other direction when you try to turn it with the rollers. And after it arrives to the stopper it starts to slip and the stopper must push against the friction force.

In case of cylindrical pipe, the rollers cannot produce any axial force and that might be true also for the conical pipe. If you think about it in terms of symmetry, when rolling in one direction, one roller might exert axial force on the conical pipe, in which case the other roller should exert essentially the opposite axial force on it.
If the rollers are driven independently, then you might be able to produce some axial force if you turn them against each other. And if they have different rpm, then you might get the cylinder turning and also some axial force.

One thing I forgot to mention, is that this conical shape is very small, only from tolerances of production errors. In theory all three axes are parallel, but in real life pipe will travel to one or the other direction when you try to turn it with the rollers. And after it arrives to the stopper it starts to slip and the stopper must push against the friction force.

@Grega The axial force will be inherently connected to these production tolerances. I don't think it is feasible to try to calculate the force. What you may try is to measure the force or some proxy variable, like the maximum axial speed. Another posibility might be to use non-cylindrical rollers (probably thicker in the central part) or use driving wheel in the center and the rollers just for support. This might work as self correction, i.e., when the pipe deviates from the center, it will be automatically drawn back to it.

I agree that evaluating the axial force that comes from production tolerances will be hard. Also, no way for me to measure the force, at least for now. I can't drive the pipe in the center under the pipe for other design reasons. Also, non-cylindrical rollers are not an option, because the pipe is cut to shorter lengths during machine operation and I need the length of roller with a constant diameter. I will design the stoppers regarding the maximum friction force for maximum length of pipe. This will do for now.

assuming the cylinder is somehow supported at the other end, and assuming it rotates slowly.
the reactions on the rollers are
$$R_h= \frac{W}{2}sin (\theta /2)$$
$$R_v= \frac{W}{2}cos(\theta/2)$$
And the axial force on the cylinder is
$$F_a= 2R_h=W*sin(theta/2)$$

Note, that this axial force is not the diameter force. You need the angle $\theta$ and calculate the moment diagram for that. But this axial force under the load of the rollers is the largest force. In fact, for $\theta<30 degrees, $ the diameter axial force will be negligible!
for the impact of the irregular shape of the cylinder, you can use your judgment and guess the imbalance and plug it in.
To stop the cylinder from rolling, you need to know the speed of rolling and how fast you want it to stop. If you have that data, let's work on it.

.

Edit
Because I didn't receive data on rolling speed and required brake time, here is the general equations. you can plug in the details.
Assuming your cylinder ie rather thin its moment of inertia is
$$I-{cylinder}= mr^2=10,000*2m^2=40,000kgm$$
$$L_{cylinder}=I\omega$$

L = angular momentum of the cylinder
$\omega = rotation speed of cylinder in radians. $
T = time it takes to stop
$\tau \ brake \ torqe$
$\mu$= constant of friction

$$T= \frac{ L}{\tau_{brake}}=\frac{ L}{[W*sin(\theta/2)+W cos(\theta/2)]\mu}$$

I don't completely understand your approach. One thing I forgot to mention, is that this conical shape is very small, only from tolerances of production errors. In theory all three axes are parallel, but in real life pipe will travel to one or the other direction when you try to turn it with the rollers. And after it arrives to the stopper it starts to slip and the stopper must push against the friction force.

@Grega I am not quite clear on what your pipe's situation is. My answer is the very basic engineering textbook answer for a pipe rolling with a constant speed on rollers, and it assumes a cylinder, not a con. It would help if you edited your question and added more detail or a diagram.

Now, I think I see where you went off - I think you misunderstood which axial force I'm talking about. It is in the direction of the axis of the pipe. Also, dynamic analysis was not what I was looking for.

You'd need first to add another roller to make it 3-roller support, say on the top. As it is this is going to fall. Or if there is more support already in place give details. Basically you are having a heavy pipe cantilevered and capable of rolling? is that right?

Where do you see the cantilever? Please post a sketch so I can see what you imagine. Then, I will be able to respond better.
